# Performance of Various Methods to Test for a Palindrome [Python]

Tags: python, string, performance

Today, I was fooling around with a couple of programming puzzles. Faced with the task of testing a string to see whether or not it is a palindrome, I conceived of several ways to accomplish this. The basics of these three methods are depicted below (most neatifying and testing code is omitted).

```
def check_palin(victim, method):
if method is 1: # check progressively inner chars
    x = 0
    while x < (len(victim)/2): # len/2 is num of iter needed for guarantee
        if victim[x+0] is victim[-(1+x)]: # on pass n, compare nth letter
                                            # and nth to last letter
            x += 1 # then increment the n counter
        else:
            return False
    return True
elif method is 2: # check first and last chars repeatedly
    tmp = []
    for i in victim:
        tmp.append(i) # convert string into list
    while len(tmp) > 1: # if 1 or 0 char left, palin is guaranteed
        if tmp[0] is tmp[-1]: # if the first and last characters are the same letter
            tmp.pop(0)  # remove them both
            tmp.pop(-1)
        else:
            return False
    return True
elif method is 3: # reverse string and compare to original
    tmp = ""
    for i in victim: # for every letter
        tmp = i + tmp # cat it to the beginning, not append          
    return tmp == victim
else:
    return -1
```

**Method 1** takes advantage of the fact that characters in a string can be indexed like elements of a list. We can imagine this method thusly: you start with your fingers under the first and last letters of a word; with each iteration, you first check whether the letters above your fingers are the same; if they are different, the word is not a palindrome; if they are the same, you move each of your fingers 1 letter toward the center of the word and repeat.

The bulk of computation with this method would be the condition testing, index slicing, and comparisons. There is also a counter variable which is a constant part of a calculation for the index slicing.

**Method 2** also employs the indexing of characters in a string. The first and last characters are compared, then discarded, and these steps are repeated until a palindrome is guaranteed (or disproven).

Costs would be similar to Method 1, with some differences: the addition of conversion from str -> list, popping elements from a list, and minus a counter variable.

**Method 3** reverses the given string, and then compares it to the original. *There are various ways to reverse a string (`list.__reversed__()`, etc.), but I've only shown one such possibility: converting the string to a list, and then concatenating each element of that list to the BEGINNING of a new string.*

With different methods for reversing a string, there may be different operations, and thus costs, involved. For my chosen method here, we have the cost of slicing each and every element from a list and concatenating it with a str variable.

## My questions:

Which of these methods would be the fastest executing and why? Also, is there any way to improve the efficiency of these methods? (On a tangent, how do you test the execution speed of modules in Python?)

Comment: There's a very easy way to find out which method is fastest: **measure their speeds**.

Comment: A oneliner for method 3: ispalin = lambda s: s == s[::-1]

Comment: Do not use `is` for comparison with anything except singletons like `True` or `False` - it may behave strangely. Python implementations are not required to make every one-char string a singleton, so the comparison may fail. Even with CPython, `2048 is 2047 + 1` is False, as is `'ab' is 'abc'[0:2]`, and another interpreter may even make `'a' is 'a'` False.

Comment: **DANGER** Don't rely on `is` giving the same result as `==` (e.g. `victim[x+0] is victim[-(1+x)]`) -- it is implementation-dependant and in C-Python only "works" with the first 256 characters (and a range of small integers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [timeit](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html#module-timeit) module for speed-testing, the [profile](http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html#module-profile) module for performance statistics, and the [dis](http://docs.python.org/library/dis.html#module-dis) module for bytecode disassembly.

The script below demonstrates how the modules can be used.

One thing to notice from the output is how much the number of function calls can affect the overall performance (and, of course, the same thing goes for the number of bytecode instructions).

Hopefully, that (and a little more experimentation) should give you enough clues on how to improve the efficiency of your functions.

```
from timeit import timeit
from cProfile import runctx
from dis import dis

def analyse(*args):
    victim = 'detartrated'
    number = 1000
    for func in args:
        print('\n%s\n' % ('#' * 50))
        name = func.__name__
        print('test: %s(%r): %r' % (name, victim, func(victim)))
        code = '%s(%r)' % (name, victim)
        duration = timeit(
            code, 'from __main__ import %s' % name, number=number)
        usec = 1000000 * duration / number
        print('time: %s: %.2f usec/pass\n' % (code, usec))
        runctx(code, globals(), locals())
        dis(func)

def check_palin1(victim):
    """ check progressively inner chars """
    x = 0
    # len/2 is num of iter needed for guarantee
    while x < (len(victim)/2):
        # on pass n, compare nth letter and nth to last letter
        if victim[x+0] is victim[-(1+x)]:
            # then increment the n counter
            x += 1
        else:
            return False
    return True

def check_palin2(victim):
    """ check first and last chars repeatedly """
    tmp = []
    for i in victim:
        # convert string into list
        tmp.append(i)
    # if 1 or 0 char left, palin is guaranteed
    while len(tmp) > 1:
        # if the first and last characters are the same letter
        if tmp[0] is tmp[-1]:
            # remove them both
            tmp.pop(0)
            tmp.pop(-1)
        else:
            return False
    return True

def check_palin3(victim):
    """ reverse string and compare to original using a loop """
    tmp = ""
    # for every letter
    for i in victim:
        # cat it to the beginning, not append
        tmp = i + tmp
    return tmp == victim

def check_palin4(victim):
    """ reverse string and compare to original using slice syntax """
    return victim == victim[::-1]

analyse(check_palin1, check_palin2, check_palin3, check_palin4)
```

Output:

```
##################################################

test: check_palin1('detartrated'): True
time: check_palin1('detartrated'): 3.80 usec/pass

         9 function calls in 0.000 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 test.py:20(check_palin1)
        6    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {len}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}


 22           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
              3 STORE_FAST               1 (x)

 24           6 SETUP_LOOP              72 (to 81)
        >>    9 LOAD_FAST                1 (x)
             12 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (len)
             15 LOAD_FAST                0 (victim)
             18 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             21 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
             24 BINARY_DIVIDE       
             25 COMPARE_OP               0 (<)
             28 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       80

 26          31 LOAD_FAST                0 (victim)
             34 LOAD_FAST                1 (x)
             37 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
             40 BINARY_ADD          
             41 BINARY_SUBSCR       
             42 LOAD_FAST                0 (victim)
             45 LOAD_CONST               3 (1)
             48 LOAD_FAST                1 (x)
             51 BINARY_ADD          
             52 UNARY_NEGATIVE      
             53 BINARY_SUBSCR       
             54 COMPARE_OP               8 (is)
             57 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       73

 28          60 LOAD_FAST                1 (x)
             63 LOAD_CONST               3 (1)
             66 INPLACE_ADD         
             67 STORE_FAST               1 (x)
             70 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            9

 30     >>   73 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (False)
             76 RETURN_VALUE        
             77 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            9
        >>   80 POP_BLOCK           

 31     >>   81 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (True)
             84 RETURN_VALUE        

##################################################

test: check_palin2('detartrated'): True
time: check_palin2('detartrated'): 10.57 usec/pass

         30 function calls in 0.000 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 test.py:33(check_palin2)
        6    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {len}
       11    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
       10    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'pop' of 'list' objects}


 35           0 BUILD_LIST               0
              3 STORE_FAST               1 (tmp)

 36           6 SETUP_LOOP              27 (to 36)
              9 LOAD_FAST                0 (victim)
             12 GET_ITER            
        >>   13 FOR_ITER                19 (to 35)
             16 STORE_FAST               2 (i)

 38          19 LOAD_FAST                1 (tmp)
             22 LOAD_ATTR                0 (append)
             25 LOAD_FAST                2 (i)
             28 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             31 POP_TOP             
             32 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           13
        >>   35 POP_BLOCK           

 40     >>   36 SETUP_LOOP              75 (to 114)
        >>   39 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (len)
             42 LOAD_FAST                1 (tmp)
             45 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             48 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
             51 COMPARE_OP               4 (>)
             54 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE      113

 42          57 LOAD_FAST                1 (tmp)
             60 LOAD_CONST               2 (0)
             63 BINARY_SUBSCR       
             64 LOAD_FAST                1 (tmp)
             67 LOAD_CONST               3 (-1)
             70 BINARY_SUBSCR       
             71 COMPARE_OP               8 (is)
             74 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE      106

 44          77 LOAD_FAST                1 (tmp)
             80 LOAD_ATTR                2 (pop)
             83 LOAD_CONST               2 (0)
             86 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             89 POP_TOP             

 45          90 LOAD_FAST                1 (tmp)
             93 LOAD_ATTR                2 (pop)
             96 LOAD_CONST               3 (-1)
             99 CALL_FUNCTION            1
            102 POP_TOP             
            103 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           39

 47     >>  106 LOAD_GLOBAL              3 (False)
            109 RETURN_VALUE        
            110 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           39
        >>  113 POP_BLOCK           

 48     >>  114 LOAD_GLOBAL              4 (True)
            117 RETURN_VALUE        

##################################################

test: check_palin3('detartrated'): True
time: check_palin3('detartrated'): 2.77 usec/pass

         3 function calls in 0.000 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 test.py:50(check_palin3)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}


 52           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('')
              3 STORE_FAST               1 (tmp)

 54           6 SETUP_LOOP              24 (to 33)
              9 LOAD_FAST                0 (victim)
             12 GET_ITER            
        >>   13 FOR_ITER                16 (to 32)
             16 STORE_FAST               2 (i)

 56          19 LOAD_FAST                2 (i)
             22 LOAD_FAST                1 (tmp)
             25 BINARY_ADD          
             26 STORE_FAST               1 (tmp)
             29 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           13
        >>   32 POP_BLOCK           

 57     >>   33 LOAD_FAST                1 (tmp)
             36 LOAD_FAST                0 (victim)
             39 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             42 RETURN_VALUE        

##################################################

test: check_palin4('detartrated'): True
time: check_palin4('detartrated'): 0.65 usec/pass

         3 function calls in 0.000 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 test.py:59(check_palin4)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}


 61           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (victim)
              3 LOAD_FAST                0 (victim)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
              9 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             12 LOAD_CONST               2 (-1)
             15 BUILD_SLICE              3
             18 BINARY_SUBSCR       
             19 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             22 RETURN_VALUE
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't do  a palindrome check faster than O(n) (n being the length of the input string). Any extra effort (stacks, reversing the string etc.) won't give you any perforce improvement, it only costs memory.

Answer (score 1):

Module timeit can be used. eg.:

```
import timeit

for method in 1, 2, 3:
   print method, timeit.timeit('check_palin("victimmitciv", %i)' % method,
                       'from __main__ import check_palin', number=1000000)
```

Answer (score 0):

For timing small pieces of code like these functions, [timeit](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html) can be very useful. Then you can find which one is faster yourself :)